# How to find the phase constant?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

I was given this velocity-vs-time graph of a particle in simple harmonic motion:

[image]

I determined the amplitude to be $A = 1.15$ m, which Mastering Physics confirmed is correct.

Then I was asked to find the phase constant. I tried a few things but finally gave up and asked Mastering Physics for the answer, which is: $\phi_0=2.62$ rad.

Since I had this equation in my notes,

$$v_x(t)=-\omega A sin(\omega t+\phi_0)=-v_\max sin(\omega t+\phi_0)$$

First I found the angular frequency $\omega$:

$$\omega = {2\pi \over T}={2\pi \over 12 s}=0.523$$

Multiplied by $A=1.15$, it matches the $v_{max}$ of 0.60 m/s shown in the graph.

Then I tried this, using $t$ = 0 s:

$$v_x(t)=-\omega A sin(\omega t+\phi_0)$$
$$-0.30=(-0.523)(1.15)sin(\omega (0)+\phi_0)$$
$$-0.30=(-0.60)sin(\phi_0)$$
$${-0.30 \over -0.60}=sin(\phi_0)$$
$$0.5=sin(\phi_0)$$
$$sin^{-1}(0.5)=\phi_0$$
$$0.523=\phi_0$$

But that just gave me the angular frequency value, not the correct answer (which is 2.62 rad).

Did I do something wrong in the calculation, or am I confusing units? My calculator was on radians mode.

Note: My algebra skills are pretty weak, so I'm thinking that's where the mistake might be... ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful about what exactly the inverse sine function is doing. If arcsin is given input x, it returns the angle, y, that sin(y) would have produced.

If you consider $\sin(x)$:

[image: Sine(x)]

You'll see that
$$
\sin(0.523) \approx 0.5 \\ \sin(2.62) \approx 0.5 \\ \sin(6.81) \approx 0.5 \\...
$$

The inverse sine function doesn't just return a single value (although most calculators will only show one). It returns an infinitely large set of discrete values.

Now as far as why the problem probably wanted the 2.62 answer has to do with assumptions on the original displacement wave function. Generally, the equation for the displacement and velocity are of the form
$$
x(t)=A \cos(\omega t + \phi)\\
\frac{dx}{dt}=v(t)=-\omega A \sin(\omega t + \phi)
$$
Below, I've generated plots of these functions, where $A=1$, $\omega=1$, and $\phi=0$. You'll see that the "unshifted" functional waveform of the velocity function is similar in shape to a -sin(x) function.

If you take a look at your original, you'll see that shifting it left by 0.523 would give a graph that looks similar to sin(x), while shifting it left by the correct answer, 2.62, would give you a graph that looks similar to a -sin(x) plot (and similar to what the "unshifted" velocity function looks like).

[image: x(t)][image]